# Entering to index page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

```
    //
    // Post: /Search/Alternativ1/txtBoxTitle)

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Alternativ1(int txtBoxTitle)
    {
        SokningMedAlternativ1 test= new SokningMedAlternativ1();

        if (txtBoxTitel != null)
        {
            var codeModel = test.FilteraBokLista(txtBoxTitel);
        }

        return View(codeModel);
    }
```

Problem:
I have problem to find a solution to go back to my index page (first page when entering a website for the first time) view if txtBoxTitle  has null.

My request:
How shall I enter to my index page view automatically if txtBoxTitle contains null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

1. Redirect to the `Index` action (sending a 302 status code to the client):

   ```
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
   ```
2. Render the `Index` view (the client keeps the original URL in the address bar, no redirect here):

   ```
   return View("Index", someModelThatTheIndexActionExpects);
   ```

If this `Index` action is located on another controller you have the possibility to specify this controller name:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

and:

```
return View("~/Views/Home/Index.aspx", someModelThatTheIndexActionExpects);
```

Remark: In your example the `txtBoxTitle` argument is declared as [`System.Int32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx), so talking about it being or not being `null` just makes absolutely no sense as this is a value type which can never be `null` and your `if` condition code won't even compile as you have it currently written.

Comment: That's true what you were saying. In this context I made the sourcecode more simplified for end user. In my orginal source code I wrote "int? txtBoxTitle" instead. Thank you for your help.

If you are still interrest in solving another problem in MVC 2, I have a problem that nobody has solved it yet.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666775/what-code-in-inherit-part